# Reverse a .htaccess redirection rule

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, redirection

Let me explain by example. Say, I have this redirection rule in my .htaccess file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ http://www.example.com/$2
```

What it basically does is, redirect `http://www.mysite.com/sports/test-post/` to `http://www.mysite.com/test-post/`.

Now, how do I modify the .htaccess rule to do the opposite? (i.e. redirect `http://www.mysite.com/test-post/` to `http://www.mysite.com/sports/test-post/`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sports/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/sports/$1/$2 [R=301]
```

This'll also send `/test-post/blah/` to `/sports/test-post/blah` - if you don't want to do the redirect when there's extra stuff on there, ditch the `(.*)` from the match string and the `$2` from the replace string.

Comment: Oops! That was just an example. `sports` can actually be any category depending on the page. So, sports can't really be in the rule. **EDIT:** Also, if possible, please provide a `RedirectMatch` rule instead of `mod_rewrite`-based one. Thanks!

Comment: @AahanKrish You'll need to clarify what your aim is, then.  How's the redirect supposed to get the correct category, when all it has is `/test-post`?  Regarding `RedirectMatch`, it can only work if you'll only ever redirect for `/test-post/` - if you want to redirect for `/test-post/blah` then `RedirectMatch` will just give you a redirect loop.

Comment: :P How stupid of me. Thanks for your answer, it solves my problem.